# How to capture the start of play from RemoteMedia

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have the following code to capture the play event but it never gets called.

```
var remoteMedia = new cast.receiver.RemoteMedia();
remoteMedia.onPlay = onPlay;


function onPlay(position){
 .....
}
```

my `onPlay` method never gets called. I have the same for onEnded and it works just fine. `onLoad` gets called but then the video never plays if I have my own function for it, even if I call `load()` inside my `onLoad` function.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried directly hooking into the Video element's events?

Comment: No I have not, I was trying to only use the `RemoteMedia` object as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did this, but just to be sure, did you call `remoteMedia.setMediaElement`? From the [Receiver user guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    var elem = document.getElementById('vid'); 
    remoteMedia.setMediaElement(elem);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I have that all working fine. There was just no event that worked when video started playing. When ending it was working fine. So I did what Ali Naddaf recommended and used the events on the actual video element, that worked out well.